# How to debug random jittering in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, hardware-failure

I have recently had my PC transported. Now when I use it the system appears to jitter. This happens intermittently, but seems to occur more frequently when it is put under increased stress.

The jitters appear to lock the system up for fractions of a second and are accompanied by an audio anomaly that sounds like a buzz.

I noticed initially after hearing the audio cues from Youtube videos, but saw it amplified when I played a 3D video game with moderate graphics requirements.

Does anybody have any idea how to determine which piece of hardware is failing?

Comment: May be the hard disk cranks. Or cooler fan blade stuck with wires.

Comment: How would I test the drive? I have liquid cooling, so it'd not going to be fan related.